# getting an OSError when trying to pip install

Tags: python, windows, pip

When I try to `pip install neuralintents` it gives me this error:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

can it be fixed if I enable windows long path, how do I do it

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip install FileNotFoundError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51405580/pip-install-filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: or [python-could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65980952/python-could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or)

Comment: the [PyPi page of `neuralintents`](https://pypi.org/project/neuralintents/) states that project is _Still in a buggy alpha state._ so that may be part of the issue

Comment: The package is possibly broken. File a [github issue on the project](https://github.com/NeuralNine/neuralintents).

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to install neuralintents with Python 3.10.0, I got a  Tensorflow error. Then I tried to install tensorflow like this:

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

After that, you can now do

```
pip install neuralintents
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).