# Unit testing ( this is where I am at now in my training )

Tags: python, unit-testing, command-line, command, pylint

WARNING: Error parsing requirements for pywinpty: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

This is what I get when I try to pip install pylint

I am also using a pycham environment

I tried pip install pywinpty to see if it will work but nop..

I tried some directory changes but nop....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Pip3 install to see your results as mentioned in this question as well.
[pip install FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51405580/pip-install-filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

If that does not work then please elaborate a bit more regarding the issue so anyone looking at your question can have a bit more context to help you.

Have a nice day.

Comment: i later figured it out 
though it took a lot of time...